# iframes sometimes not loading iOS 10 Xcode 8 ionic

Tags: xcode, cordova, iframe, ionic-framework, ios10

I have a report on my website that I want to use in my ionic app. I have a page on my app that loads the report inside an iframe. The report has three graphs on it that are each in a separate iframe. The report loads just fine. The graphs on the report load about 50% of the time. When I refresh the page, I get different results. Sometimes they all load. Sometimes only two load.

This works just fine on Android, but it does not work reliably on iOS.

Also, I'm getting this in my Xcode console and I'm not sure if it is related:

```
WF: _userSettingsForUser mobile: {
    filterBlacklist =   {
    };
    filterWhitelist =   {
    };
    restrictWeb = 1;
    useContentFilter = 0;
    useContentFilterOverrides = 0;
    whitelistEnabled = 0;
    }

WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS 10 "Starting WebFilter logging for process" + Proxy-Authorization header removed from request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39635505/ios-10-starting-webfilter-logging-for-process-proxy-authorization-header-rem)